# Should I move from http to https?

Tags: https

From what I understand good practices are now to use more and more https.
I was wondering if I can redirect all my websites from http to https, or are there cases where https cannot be used?

Comment: Although no-one seems to be interested in the matter, after some research it looks like it's a really complex topic : there are lots of possible cypher and client compatibility is far from obvious.